# jQuery's position().left changing when Raphael JS's setViewBox changes in FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, raphael

I've included a jsfiddle showing a problem I'm having with jQuery and Raphael in Firefox. When I move a jQuery UI slider, the circle in the Raphael canvas gets larger. Below the slider, I print out the canvas's left position. In Chrome and Internet Explorer, left remains constant as the slider is moved. In FireFox, however, left changes as the slider is moved back and forth.

```
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="slider"></div>
<div id="left1">left: <span id="left2"></span></div>

var x = 1;
r = Raphael('test', 100, 100);
r.canvas.className.baseVal="canvas";
r.circle(40,40,10);
$('#slider').slider({

slide: function (e, ui){
x = ui.value;
    r.setViewBox((r.canvas.getAttribute('width')/2) -((r.canvas.getAttribute('width')*.5)/x), (r.canvas.getAttribute('height')/2) - ((r.canvas.getAttribute('height')*.5)/x), r.canvas.getAttribute('width')/x, r.canvas.getAttribute('height')/x);

$('#left2').text($(r.canvas).position().left); 
}

});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XfQgV/15/

Any idea why left changes in FireFox?

Answer (score 1):

I've been informed that jQuery has problems with SVG elements, as shown by this bug:

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9797

A solution that fixes my problem is to use the SVG element's bounding box instead of jQuery position. So, I replaced every

$(r.canvas).position().left

with document.getElementById('my_id').getBBox().x